# iText: PdfTable cell vertical alignment

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertical align my headet cell text to be in the middle of the cell height.

This is my code:

```
    PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(cerate_phrase("" ,regular_bold ));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    c1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    c1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
    table_.addCell(c1);
```

but this does not work. `setHorizontalAlignment` is centered but not `setVerticalAlignment`.

Am I doing something wrong? how can i vertically align it in the middle?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This question has been asked (and answered) on several occasions.  Search for PdfCell vertical alignment.

Comment: @ Mark Storer: I found this question :iText - vertical alignment not working in composite mode - but it did not worked for me. any ideas?

Comment: @MarkStorer Could you link to the dupe? My search didn't turn up anything.

Answer (score 28):

According to Lowagie:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("blah Blah blah");
cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

This is always correct in a technical sense, but sometimes looks bad.

To center, draw a box around the object, find its middle, and align it with the center of its surrounding object.

iText thus finds the center of the phrase, and aligns it. But human eyes sometimes focus on the bulk of text, say the parts of the font between the baseline and the cap height. So to have it look good, you need to center relative to that.

```
Phrase content = new Phrase("Blah blah blah", Font);

Float fontSize = content.getFont().getSize();
Float capHeight = content.getFont().getBaseFont().getFontDescriptor(BaseFont.CAPHEIGHT, fontSize);

Float padding = 5f;    

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(content);
cell.setPadding(padding);
cell.setPaddingTop(capHeight - fontSize + padding);
```

Note that the PdfPCell method setVerticalAlignment(..) isn't used.

It seems like this wouldn't necessarily work for a multi-line phrase, but it does.

[image: Typography Line Terms]

The problem would be obvious if iText could show bounding boxes around things (mind, you *can* tell iText to draw bounding boxes, it's just more work than a magical on/off switch).

This solution is adapted from an [email from Paulo Soares](http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01229.html).

Comment: The idea is good, but it doesn't work perfectly .. I don't think that the float "padding" should be fixed to "5f"

Comment: try this: `setPaddingBottom(2*(fontSize-capHeight));` and you call `setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);`

Comment: @djeikyb super you saved my time..Thanks +1 vote for your answer.

Answer (score 26):

Add `cell.setUseAscender(true)` before `c1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);`
I have the same problem with you, when add code above I find it can work, hope this can solve your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `ExtraParagraphSpace`:

```
c1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
c1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
c1.ExtraParagraphSpace = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do like this :

```
cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
cell.setUseAscender(true);
```